# Oracle PL/SQL Procedimiento almacenado que regrese tablas

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, stored-procedure, plsql

tengo las siguientes tablas (2 tablas catálogos y 1 tabla que almacena mi información, relacionadas con Clave foráneas) en Oracle Database 19c:

- CTLG_TIPO_UBICACIONES
- CTLG_TIPO_ACCION
- UBICACIONES

Tal como indica en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Tablas]

Soy nuevo en eso de los Procedimientos almacenados, necesito hacer el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

**SP_PARAMETROS**(OUT **TOTALES_TIPO_UBICACIONES**, OUT **TOTALES_TIPO_ACCION**, OUT **TOTAL_DE_UBICACIONES**)

Tal como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Parámetros de salida]

He intentado "fusionar / unir" cada tabla CTLG con un campo "virtual" TOTALES, pero no lo he podido lograr (Desconozco si se puede hacer esto).

Me han sugerido que a las tablas CTLG le agregue el campo TOTALES, pero implicaría el estar actualizando dichas tablas cada vez que se haga un INSERT INTO o DELETE en la tabla UBICACIONES y repercutiría el rendimiento.

**¿Me pueden apoyar con la solución?, por favor.**

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones o sugerencias terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Te respondo porque no creo haya muchas recomendaciones distintas. Tu problema es muy común y tampoco hay tantas formas de resolverlo. Salvo que te encuentres con un purista teórico que te recomiende no registrar nunca datos calculados, pero hay veces que resulta bastante cómodo tenerlos a mano en una tabla.

No necesitas un procedimiento almacenado, sino un disparador o `TRIGGER`. Aunque también puedes llamar al procedimiento almacenado desde el disparador que, en esencia, es lo mismo.

Por supuesto que afecta al rendimiento, pero tienes que decidir si prefieres calcular esos totales

- cada vez que los necesites a través de un `SELECT` con `GROUP BY` o
- cada vez que hagas un `INSERT` o un `DELETE`.

Lo mejor para el rendimiento, será calcular esos totales el menor número de veces posible. Ahí no te queda más opción que intuir el uso que se hará de su software.

Para ayudarte más, debes aportar tu dataset y el código de tu intento.

Answer (score 0):

En lo que a pura consulta se refiere, estas *queries* deberían devolver los datos que necesitas:

```
SELECT CTLG_TIPO_UBICACIONES.ID_TIPO_UBICACION,
       CTLG_TIPO_UBICACIONES.NOM_TIPO_UBICACION,
       COUNT(UBICACIONES.ID_PRODUCTO) AS TOTALES
FROM CTLG_TIPO_UBICACIONES
LEFT JOIN UBICACIONES ON CTLG_TIPO_UBICACIONES.ID_TIPO_UBICACION = UBICACIONES.TIPO_UBICACION
GROUP BY CTLG_TIPO_UBICACIONES.ID_TIPO_UBICACION, CTLG_TIPO_UBICACIONES.NOM_TIPO_UBICACION;

SELECT CTLG_TIPO_ACCION.ID_TIPO_ACCION,
       CTLG_TIPO_ACCION.NOM_TIPO_ACCION,
       COUNT(UBICACIONES.ID_PRODUCTO) AS TOTALES
FROM CTLG_TIPO_ACCION
LEFT JOIN UBICACIONES ON CTLG_TIPO_ACCION.ID_TIPO_ACCION = UBICACIONES.TIPO_ACCION
GROUP BY CTLG_TIPO_ACCION.ID_TIPO_ACCION, CTLG_TIPO_ACCION.NOM_TIPO_ACCION;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_DE_UBICACIONES FROM UBICACIONES;
```

Como te han comentado antes, sería conveniente que incluyas el código del procedimiento que has escrito para poder comprobar cuál es el problema. Un saludo.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32e82c/1